# In Formprocessor fill an email template with values from parameters from the form

Tags: form-processor, action-provider

In the extension Form Processor I'd like to perform the action to send an email. I lookup an email template (with action "Communication: Get message template by name"), and I would like to fill it with some parameters I got from the form, or some action I performed before. How can I insert those parameters?

Can the template contain tokens or placeholders that can be replaced in form processor?

What's the way to go if I want to send out an email containing data from or derived from the contents in the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this should be possible with the `Other: Replace tokens in HTML` action, though it seems to only accept a few different entity IDs (the most common ones though).

If you need to add information that's part of the input but not a true "token", it seems possible but onerous.  You would:

- make your own "token" - e.g. `<placeholder for submitter's name>`
- use the `Set Value` action to create an input with that text, e.g `placeholder_1`.
- Use the `Other: Replace text` to search your template HTML, *Value* would be `placeholder_1`, `replacement` would be the field you want to insert into your text.